# how can i connect to some existing account?

Tags: android, permissions, accounts

I am trying to  add my google account to the: `Settings -> Accounts` on my phone.

The account is already created and working but I am not able to connect programmatically.

I have already tried following:

```
    AccountManager accountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
    Account account = new Account("username@gmail.com","com.google");
    boolean success = accountManager.addAccountExplicitly(account,"password",null);
```

but the app keeps crashing, i believe due to permission problems. tried to find the right permissions but couldn't manage. If someone can show me the full way to do it, it would be great.

Comment: use these two permoissions in manifest  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />` and   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> and if you are using sdk version 23 and above then you have to give runtime permissions in your app

Comment: *i believe due to permission problems* then please post error log as well

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.proj1/com.example.proj1.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: uid 10236 cannot explicitly add accounts of type: com.google

Comment: i added the permissions :  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS, Manifest.permission.INTERNET}, 0);  -- on run time and on manifast: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />